# What is the probability distribution of the absolute value of the vandermonde determinant over a finite field

Tags: probability-distributions, determinant, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime.  We select $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ randomly and uniformly.  Let $V$ denote the Vandermonde determinant
$$
V_n= \left\vert\begin{matrix}
  1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & \cdots & x_1^{n-2} & x_1^{n-1} \\
  1 & x_2 & x_2^2 & \cdots & x_2^{n-2} & x_2^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_n & x_n^2 & \cdots & x_n^{n-2} & x_n^{n-1}
\end{matrix}\right\vert mod  p.
$$
of the elments of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

What is the probability distribution of the vandermonde determinant over a finite field $\mathbb{Z}_p$?